# Adding numbers within a text file (python)

Tags: python

Hi i have been given a task to read these numbers from within a text file "1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15," and to add them together how would i do this? So far i have:

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\Dylan\\Python\\OddNumbersAns.txt", "r")
line = file.read()
intline = int(line)
print(intline)
```

But i recieve this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dylan\Python\text file add.py", line 3, in <module>
    intline = int(line)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, '
```

Thanks

Answer:

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\Dylan\\Python\\OddNumbersAns.txt", "r")

line = file.read()

line.split(",")

print (line.split(","))

total = sum([int(num) for num in line.split(',')])

print(total)
```

Comment: You're trying to turn the entire line into a single integer.  You need to split it up into separate strings first, going by the commas.  Investigate the `split` function.

Comment: Is your name Dylan by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the sum() function, after splitting the line on every comma:

```
total = sum(int(num) for num in line.split(','))
```

Don't try to call `int(line)`, as that's trying to turn the whole line into a single int.

Instead, you split the line on every comma, yielding a sequence of strings, each of which is cast to `int`. Putting the whole thing in the sum function adds them together.

Comment: Don't need to make the list, you can call sum like this: `total = sum(int(num) for num in line.split(','))`. Probably will increases a little in performance. +1 for using `sum`.

Comment: `total = sum(map(int, line.split(','))`. Even if BDFL doesn't like it, it looks more concise and clear to me.

Comment: @PauloBu - you're right, of course. The inclusion of the list was redundant here; I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains trailing new line or comma:

```
#a.txt
1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 
2, 3, 45, 6,
```

you need to `strip` it first, then `split`:

```
In [174]: with open('a.x', 'r') as f:
     ...:     line=f.read()
     ...:     total=sum(map(int, line.strip(', \n').split(',')))
     ...:     print total
#output: 120
```

without `strip`, e.g. `'1,2,\n'` would be splitted into `['1', '2', '\n']`, and `int('\n')` or `int('')` would raise a ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic stuff you need

```
>>> txt_line = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"
>>> 
>>> [int(ele.strip()) for ele in txt_line.split(",")]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> sum([int(ele.strip()) for ele in txt_line.split(",")])
36
>>>
```

In addition to this you may have to take care of the file inputs
It could either be complete file content or line by line read
So I would recommend the following

```
with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        ## Here insert the above logic
        line = fp.readline()
```